# celery daemonization with Docker Alpine - celeryd down: no pidfiles found

Tags: python, docker, celery, pid, alpine-linux

I'm trying to setup the celery daemon to run at startup in an Alpine docker container.

This is the Dockerfile section:

```
# adding OpenRC for enabling/starting services
RUN apk add openrc --no-cache
RUN mkdir -p /etc/default

# Celery daemon setup
COPY docker/celeryd /etc/init.d/
COPY docker/celeryd.conf /etc/default/celeryd
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/celeryd
RUN addgroup celery
RUN adduser celery -G celery -s /bin/sh -D
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/celery/ && chown celery:celery /var/log/celery/
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/celery/ && chown celery:celery /var/run/celery/
RUN rc-update add /etc/init.d/celeryd default
```

the celeryd script is this:

`https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd`

and the celery configuration file (`docker/celeryd.conf`) content is:

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most people will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="celery"

# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="config.celery:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/var/www/my_proj/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
#CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
# Configure node-specific settings by appending node name to arguments:
#CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 -c 8 -c:worker2 4 -c:worker3 2 -Ofair:worker1"

# Set logging level to DEBUG
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists (e.g., nobody).
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

the build run successfully, however on running the container and checking celeryd status I got this:

```
/var/www/my_proj # /etc/init.d/celeryd status
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
celeryd down: no pidfiles found
```

while I have no problems on starting it manually:

```
/var/www/my_proj # /etc/init.d/celeryd start
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
celery multi v4.1.0 (latentcall)
> Starting nodes...
    > worker@0600bf7dec4a: OK
```

any hints about what it can be?

Thanks

Comment: How have you setup the init system to run in the container at startup?

Comment: @Matt there's the Dockerfile section I posted.

Comment: Sorry I meant the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` part. Most containers don't run an init system so you would need to do something to get openrc to do it's thing at container startup.

Comment: e.g https://github.com/danilofalcao/dockerfiles/blob/master/alpine/Dockerfile

Comment: @Matt thanks for the hint.
Actually I havent' added any CMD or ENTRYPOINT directive since reading the Alpine docs I assumed this should be executed automatically once you added it as a service. 
How should I modify the Dockerfile for that?

Comment: @Matt just modified the Dockerfile to include the OpenRC setup:
http://dpaste.com/1K51867
but after running the container through `docker-compose up` and accessing the web container, the cmd `ps -a` does not show any celery daemon running.

Any hints?

Comment: OK. Does celery need to run in the same container as the app?  If your running a wsgi app I assume you will need a web server as well. Can you it out into a container per process/service?  Most container management likes to have a single process per container

Comment: @Matt Yes it has to live in the same container. 
I also tried in another way: I added a script `run_celery.sh`: http://dpaste.com/034HXHT
and copied that to the filesystem thorugh the Dockerfile. I also added an ENTRYPOINT or CMD directive at the end: http://dpaste.com/3AA7GPH
but again, accessing to the container and running `ps -a` does not show any celery process.
From within the container, if I run `/run_celery` the daemon starts properly.

Comment: Not sure, I guess check `docker logs` for errors at startup but I'm not that familiar with running openrc in docker.  If I ever need multiple services I use [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/overview.html) via [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) e.g [Dockerfile](https://github.com/deployable/node-docker-demo-app/blob/9d58d6212ade5264f51c5ace8200c86af6000081/Dockerfile.s6)

Comment: Don't use celery as a init process, container are not made for it. Instead, try running celery command(`celery -A ProjectA worker --autoscale=6,6 --concurrency=100`) as a foreground process for container using `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`.